# Filter two different cells by date in TableViewController - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my TableViewController I have two different types of custom cells.
One displays data from my webpage and the other displays tweets from TwitterKit.

At the moment, all my cells from the data from the webpage is displayed first, and then all the tweets comes after those.

How can I make the TableViewController filter the cells by dates and display them according to the date?

Here is what I do now:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell", for: indexPath) as! articleTableViewCell
    let cellTwitter = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "twitterCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...

    if indexPath.row < feedItems.count {
        let item: LocationModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! LocationModel

        // STUFF HERE FROM THE WEB

        return cell
    } else {
        let tweet = tweetData[(indexPath.row - feedItems.count)]

        // STUFF HERE TWEETS

        return cellTwitter
    }
}
```

**EDIT WITH HOW DATA IS STORED**

```
func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) { 
    feedItems = items
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func twitterDownloaded(items: [Any]) {
    tweetData = TWTRTweet.tweets(withJSONArray: items)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but dequeueing always both cells – although only one is used in practice – is unnecessarily inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You should have kind a view data which keeps type of your data and the data itself

```
enum DataType {
    case feed
    case tweet
}    

class ViewData {
     var type: DatTypeEnum //enum of your cell types feed, tweet
     var feddData: FeedData?
     var tweetData: TweetData?
}
```

in viewDidLoad or init method convert your data to array of ViewModel

```
var viewData: [ViewData] = convert2ViewModel(/*source*/) 


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell", for: indexPath) as! articleTableViewCell
        let cellTwitter = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "twitterCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        // Configure the cell...

        if (viewData[indexPath.row].type == .feed {
            let item: LocationModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! LocationModel

            // STUFF HERE FROM THE WEB

            return cell
        } else {
            let tweet = viewData[(indexPath.row)]

            // STUFF HERE TWEETS


            return cellTwitter

        }
    }
```

There could some syntax errors, sorry...

Comment: The term "ViewModel" assumes that the OP is using the MVVM design pattern, which may or may not be the case. MVC is the norm for iOS development.

Comment: @DuncanC, agree, will change it to ViewData

Comment: No, in MVC the appropriate place is in the Model object.

Comment: @mihatel I have updated the question with code of how I parse the data to the `feedItems` and ´tweetData´. How can I use your enums to parse the data into that?

Comment: Will have a look in 2-3 hours

Comment: @mihatel I appreciate you taking the time to help me!

Comment: @MalthePedersen: It is really hard to give a good option as don't know the data structure neither cell nor feed/tweet, but as a workaround you can add var date: Date to DataView and when receiving data from feed or tweet add it to var viewData: [ViewData] array with the date from that objects, then sort by date viewData.sorted(by: { $0.date! < $1.date!}) and after that reload data

Answer (score 0):

You don't "filter cells".

A table view displays content from your data model.

The `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method builds cells that display content from your data model.

You need to decide what your data model looks like. If you have 2 groups of cells, one for data from your web page and another for data from `TwitterKit`, you might want to think about putting each into different sections of your table view.

When you receive the data from your web page and from `TwitterKit`, filter and sort it into the form you want and install it in the data model that you use for your table view. Then have your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method simply configure cells to show the data from your data model.